# Cant add data to Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make a simple Gridview application and I have found an example on the internet and made some changes. I have one problem and am confused about one thing. The problem is I can't add data to gridview in edit mode. I set a breakpoint at Gridview RowCommand Property and saw that all the textbox values are empty. It's probably a silly mistake but I don't know where it is. And there is one more thing, while adding data we use this code:

```
(e.CommandName.Equals("ADD"))
```

I didn't understand but there is no `(e.CommandName.Equals("Update"))` or anything like that in the code. How is the update button triggered in this case?.

Thanks in advance.

This is My Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEmployeeDetails" runat="server" Width="600px" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true"
     onrowcommand="gvEmployeeDetails_RowCommand" 
     onrowdeleting="gvEmployeeDetails_RowDeleting" 
     onrowupdating="gvEmployeeDetails_RowUpdating" 
     onrowcancelingedit="gvEmployeeDetails_RowCancelingEdit" 
     onrowediting="gvEmployeeDetails_RowEditing"
     HeaderStyle-BackColor="#4D4D4D"
     HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
     <Columns>            
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee ID">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblEmpID" 
                     runat="server" 
                     Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "empid") %>'>
                 </asp:Label>
             </ItemTemplate>
             <EditItemTemplate>            
                 <asp:Label ID="lblEditEmpID" 
                     runat="server" 
                     Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "empid") %>'>
                 </asp:Label>            
             </EditItemTemplate>
             <FooterTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddEmpID" runat="server" Width="100px">
                 </asp:TextBox>
             </FooterTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" 
                     Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name") %>'>
                 </asp:Label>
             </ItemTemplate>
             <EditItemTemplate>            
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditName" runat="server" 
                     Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name") %>'>
                 </asp:TextBox>            
             </EditItemTemplate>
             <FooterTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddName" runat="server" Width="100px">
                 </asp:TextBox>
             </FooterTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Designation">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblDesignation" runat="server" 
                     Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "designation") %>'>
                 </asp:Label>
             </ItemTemplate>
             <EditItemTemplate>            
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditDesignation" runat="server" 
                     Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "designation") %>'>
                 </asp:TextBox>            
             </EditItemTemplate>
             <FooterTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddDesignation" runat="server" Width="150px">
                 </asp:TextBox>
             </FooterTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server"
                     Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "city") %>'>
                 </asp:Label>
             </ItemTemplate>
             <EditItemTemplate>            
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditCity" runat="server" 
                     Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "city") %>'>
                 </asp:TextBox>            
             </EditItemTemplate>
             <FooterTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddCity" runat="server" Width="80px">
                 </asp:TextBox>
             </FooterTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" 
                     Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "country") %>'>
                 </asp:Label>
             </ItemTemplate>
             <EditItemTemplate>            
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditCountry" runat="server" 
                     Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "country") %>'>
                 </asp:TextBox>            
             </EditItemTemplate>
             <FooterTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddCountry" runat="server" Width="80px">
                 </asp:TextBox>
             </FooterTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" 
                     ImageUrl="~/Images/icon-edit.png" Height="32px" Width="32px"/>
                 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" 
                     ImageUrl="~/Images/Delete.png"/>
             </ItemTemplate>
             <EditItemTemplate>
                 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" 
                     ImageUrl="~/Images/icon-update.png"/>
                 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                     ImageUrl="~/Images/icon-Cancel.png"/>
             </EditItemTemplate>
             <FooterTemplate>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnAdd" runat="server" CommandName="ADD" 
                     Text="Add" Width="80px">
                 </asp:LinkButton> 
              </FooterTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>

      </Columns>            
  </asp:GridView>
```

And this is the aspx.cs file:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Database=Northwind;User Id=sa ;Password=1234");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindData();
    }

    void BindData() {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable FromTable = new DataTable();
        string cmd = "select * from EmployeeDetails";

        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, conn);
        adp.Fill(ds);
        FromTable = ds.Tables[0];

        if (FromTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            gvEmployeeDetails.DataSource = FromTable;
            gvEmployeeDetails.DataBind();
        }
        else {
            FromTable.Rows.Add(FromTable.NewRow());
            gvEmployeeDetails.DataSource = FromTable;
            gvEmployeeDetails.DataBind();
            int TotalColumns = gvEmployeeDetails.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
            gvEmployeeDetails.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
            gvEmployeeDetails.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
            gvEmployeeDetails.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = TotalColumns;
            gvEmployeeDetails.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No records Found";
        }
    }
    protected void gvEmployeeDetails_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
```

///dont post this part It works

```
    }
    protected void gvEmployeeDetails_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gvEmployeeDetails.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindData();
    }
    protected void gvEmployeeDetails_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void gvEmployeeDetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName.Equals("ADD"))
        {
            TextBox txtAddEmpID = (TextBox)gvEmployeeDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddEmpID");
            TextBox txtAddName = (TextBox)gvEmployeeDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddName");
            TextBox txtAddDesignation = (TextBox)gvEmployeeDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddDesignation");
            TextBox txtAddCity = (TextBox)gvEmployeeDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddCity");
            TextBox txtAddCountry = (TextBox)gvEmployeeDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddCountry");

            conn.Open();
            string cmdstr = "insert  EmployeeDetails values(@empid,@name,@designation,@city,@country)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", txtAddEmpID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtAddName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@designation", txtAddDesignation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", txtAddCity.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", txtAddCountry.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            BindData();
        }       
    }
    protected void gvEmployeeDetails_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gvEmployeeDetails.EditIndex = -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the gridview on the page load, so every time the page loads the text and other controls gets cleared. 
Can you bind data only if not ispostback and check?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindData();
    }
    }
```

Regarding your question,
You have a link button with Command name Edit. This is the name of the command which grid view uses to trigger the edit mode for the selected row. Youn can add any type of command controls here, as far as the command name is "Edit", the edit mode will be triggerred. If you dont add this control, and set AutoGenerateEditButton=true, then by default gridview will generate and edit button, with "Edit" as the command name.

Comment: @Thakn you Kiran ,Sorry for my english but did you understand the other question

Comment: I think, i understood your quesion, updated the answer above.